# How to respond based on arguments in java constructor

Tags: java, constructor, argument-validation

I have a MVC type architecture for new user registration to my app.
The user submits the registration form to the controller servlet. This servlet extracts the user parameters and passes them to a class constructor, which represents (and returns) a template(or dummy) user with all the fields initialized based on the arguments.

I remember people insisting on argument validation in methods or constructors before using them.
Now I try to check the arguments for their validity(for example they are not null).
So when I find any argument having invalid value, How do I notify the servlet that this particular argument is invalid, because I cannot return a value from the constructor.

Please help me.

Comment: How about an Exception? For instance IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: Ya, but how would the servlet know that this particular parameter is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate before calling the constructor. If anything is wrong get back to user with error.
If everything is fine then only call constructor and create objects.

Comment: But, someday some other person may use my user class and suppose he doesn't implement validation before calling the constructor(relying on me to have implemented the validation in the constructor.)

Comment: @DigvijayYadav: As others mentioned Throwing exception will be a good way of handling this scenario. Also while creating your class thinking about what class gonna do is more important than what data others gonna provide to it.

Comment: Ok, now I got what you mean. So I need to implement validation before calling the constructor and also throw an exception from the constructor for users who don't implement validation before calling the constructor.
Thanx.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav: Yes. Because validating every possible case in constructor will make it very complex.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another service or some class to validate your data, and throw exception from  method or pass message back to servlet

Comment: How would I tell the servlet about that particular argument that has caused the problem?

Comment: By returning message from or by throwing exception

Comment: Ok, but in future my user class will always need to use the services of the validator class.

Comment: Thanx a lot your answer helped me a lot.
I need implement validation in both places before calling the constructor and in the constructor also.

Answer (score 0):

Do validation in servlet before calling the constructor. If validation fails forward to an error.jsp where you display which input parameter was null or invalid.